# How to convert array of specific keys to an Object python

Tags: python

I am writing a script in Python. The script uses `pyreadstat` library. From the library I am calling `read_sas7bdat` function it is returning dataframe. The code:

```
df = pyreadstat.read_sas7bdat(FILE_LOC, row_offset=START_FROM_ROW, row_limit=PAGE_SIZE)
finalList = []
for key in df[0]:
    l = list(map(lambda x: str(x) if str(x) == "nan" else x, df[0][key].tolist()))
    nparray = {key: l}
    finalList.append(nparray)
return json.dumps(finalList)
```

Following is the response I get as an array of object like this:

```
[
    {
        "fruits": [
            "banana",
            "apple",
            "oranges",
            "kiwi",
            "pineapple"
        ]
    },
    {
        "calories": [
            "10",
            "20",
            "10",
            "15",
            "60"
        ]
    }
]
```

And I want to convert it into in:

```
[
    {
        "fruits": "banana",
        "calories": "10"
    },
    {
        "fruits": "apple",
        "calories": "20"
    },
    {
        "fruits": "oranges",
        "calories": "10"
    },
    {
        "fruits": "kiwi",
        "calories": "15"
    },
    {
        "fruits": "pineapple",
        "calories": "60"
    }
]
```

This is how `df` looks like

```
(  fruits calories
0  banana   10
1  apple   20, <pyreadstat._readstat_parser.metadata_container object at 0x7f2e38f5f100>)
```

How can it be done in `Python`?

Comment: What does `df` look like? Instead of those conversions you are doing, `df.to_dict(orient="records")` may be what you want.

Comment: I have updated the `df` in the question. If I do `df.to_dict(orient="records")` I got AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'to_dict'

Comment: `df` is not a dataframe at all. It's a 2-element tuple where the first element is a 2-row, 2-column dataframe and the second element is some kind of pyreadstat metadata thing.

Comment: try `df[0].to_dict(orient="records"` then lol

Comment: By the way, **do not import libraries other than `pandas` under the name `pd`**. In `pd.read_sas7bdat`, you appear to have imported `pyreadstat` as `pd`. This is extremely confusing, and will cause problems for both you and other people who need to read your code.

Comment: agreed. I have updated the code

Comment: Another trick that can make code more readable is to expand the function return immediately - `df, metadata = pyreadstat.read_sas7bdat( ... )`. That way you are not calling a tuple a "df" potentially confusing future readers (including future self!).

Answer (score 0):

```
newJsonList = []
for i in range(5):
    aDict = {}
    for j in range(len(data)):
        aDict[ list(data[j].keys())[0] ] = list(data[j].values())[0][i]
    newJsonList.append(aDict)
print(json.dumps(newJsonList))
```

But also `df.to_dict(orient='records')` results the same <- Thanks @tdelaney